# How to make headers glossy in IE7,8,9 using CSS

Tags: styles, css

I am using below code to get a glossy look for a header label. It works fine in FF, Chrome and IE10. But when loaded in lower versions of IE like IE7,8,9. Glossy finish is lost. Can any body help me to get glossy look on the header?? Please refer to the below images for glossy look and normal look.

Glossy Header
[image: Glossy Header]

Normal Header
[image: Normal Header]

```
.docTitle
{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 99.3%;

        font: bold 12px/100% Arial,Verdana,helvetica;
    padding: 8px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.9);
    background: #255182;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2f4f88, #385993 49%, #21427d 50%, #255182);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2f4f88, #385993 49%, #21427d 50%, #255182);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2f4f88, #385993 49%, #21427d 50%, #255182);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2f4f88, #385993 49%, #21427d 50%, #255182);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2f4f88, #385993 49%, #21427d 50%, #255182);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the "notes" and "resources" on this page: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients. Older IE does not support the css3 gradients, but there are workarounds if its important enough to you. I personally would be fine with a "non-glossy" appearance in IE.

http://css3pie.com/ is one option for emulating support in IE.

Comment: Thanks a lot It is very helpful